# Magento 2 OWL carrousel filtered by custom attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, owl-carousel

I am trying to get the OWL carrousel to show products filtered by a custom attribute that I added.

This filter option is not supported by default. Does anybody know a good way to fix this?

Comment: which code you have try? And what error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

For the people looking for this, I have fixed this with a workaround by making a seperate category for the attributes and adding the category_id tag in the carousels as mentioned in the Porto Manual